# spectrum of two bounded linear operators

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Suppose that L and B are bounded linear operator on H, assume $0\in  \rho(L) \cap \rho(L+B)$ and that $L^{-1}$ is compact. Prove that L+B also has a compact inverse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that the compact operators form a two-sided ideal in $B(X)$ for any normed vector space $X$.

Writing $T=L^{-1}LT$ shows that every bounded operator is therefore compact. In particular your $(L+B)^{-1}$.

**Remark:** actually, the existence of a compact invertible operator in $B(X)$ is equivalent to $X$ being finite-dimensional. Indeed, this is equivalent to the identity being compact, hence to the closed unit ball being compact. If **$X$ has finite dimension**, it follows from the equivalence of norms that the closed unit ball is compact. And if the closed unit ball is compact, it is a consequence of [Riesz's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma#Some_consequences) that $X$ has finite dimension.

Comment: @user220055 Just to guarantee that $L$ is invertible and $L+B$ is invertible. That's equivalent.